# Use spaces into the tab titles with liferay tabs

Tags: spring-mvc, tabs, liferay, portlet

I'm working with Spring MVC for portlets and liferay tabs. I'm having a problem to put spaces into the tab title. Let's say I want to define something like this inside a JSP:

```
<liferay-ui:tabs
names="Sample Tab 1, Sample Tab 2"
refresh="false"
value="${myControllerValue}" 
>
<liferay-ui:section>
     <jsp:include page='/jsp/myPage1.jsp' flush="true"/> 
</liferay-ui:section>
<liferay-ui:section>
    <jsp:include page='/jsp/myPage2.jsp' flush="true"/> 
</liferay-ui:section>
</liferay-ui:tabs>
```

This is not working at all (Eventhough, it's exactly the example from the documentation) and the problem is just the spaces into the names (It works fine if I use names="tab1,tab2", but that's not what I want to show in the tab titles)

Besides, I need to control the tab I show from the controller. Something like this:

```
 if(whatever){
 renderrequest.setAttribute("myControllerValue", "Sample Tab 1");
 }
```

And this causes another problem, because I need to show the tab names in several languages, so I'd need to pass the tab I want in the locale language to match the jsp id. The best thing to do would be to split the title from the tab id and use the tabValues param, but no idea how to do it...

I read something about redefine the Languages-ext.properties, but I just import the tab,

```
<%@taglib prefix="liferay-ui"   uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" %>
```

So I don't have this properties file, and no clue how to solve it.

I'd really appreciate any kind of help with this issue.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Trying to apply the answer posted below I'm having the next error:

```
07:26:12,297 ERROR [PortletLocalServiceImpl:542] com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Error on line 20 of document  : cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'resource-bundle'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd":portlet-info, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd":portlet-preferences, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd":security-role-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd":supported-processing-event, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd":supported-publishing-event, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd":supported-public-render-parameter, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd":container-runtime-option}' is expected.
```

And this is my portlet.xml file:

```
<portlet-app
version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd">
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>MyAPP</portlet-name>
    <display-name>MyAPP</display-name>
    <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
        <value>/WEB-INF/portlet/MyAPP-portlet.xml</value>
    </init-param>                       
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
    <supported-locale>gl_ES</supported-locale>
    <supported-locale>es_ES</supported-locale>
    <resource-bundle>messages</resource-bundle>

    <resource-bundle>content/Language</resource-bundle>  

    <portlet-info>
        <title>MyAPP</title>
        <short-title>MyAPP</short-title>
        <keywords>MyAPP</keywords>
    </portlet-info>
</portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Language.properties` to have the exact title names you want in the tab.

In the `<liferay-ui:tabs>` you can have:

```
<liferay-ui:tabs
    names="sample-tab-1, sample-tab-2"
    refresh="false"
    value="${myControllerValue}" 
>
```

which are nothing but keys in the `Language.properties` files as:

```
sample-tab-1=Sample Tab 1
sample-tab-2=Sample Tab 2
```

You can define the `Language.properties` file in the `portlet.xml` as:

```
<portlet>
    ...
    ...
    <resource-bundle>content/Language</resource-bundle>
    ...
</portlet>
```

And this file and other Language files would reside in the source package inside the `content` folder, something like this:

```
docroot
  |
  |--> src
        |
        |--> content
                |--> Language.properties
                |--> Language_en.properties
                |--> Language_ja.properties
                |--> Language_de.properties
                     ...
```

So in your controller you would use:

```
if(whatever){
   renderrequest.setAttribute("myControllerValue", "sample-tab-1");
}
```

More about [Liferay Localization](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/localize-your-portlet).

Comment: Have you tried this approach? I've already fix my problem using a hook to the liferay Language.properties, but if this works, it seems an easier solution. I've tried to do what you said, but I'm not able even to deploy my portlet (Notice that I already have some properties defined in my portlet for the language management). Besides, I still don't get how could the liferay tabs know where these files are located, and use it instead of the liferay ones...

Comment: @elcadro `<resource-bundle>content/Language</resource-bundle>` is enough for the container to know where to fetch the values of the keys for your portlet. We use this way to store are Language files and if you see liferay plugin portlets from the Marketplace then you would know that Liferay also uses this same way for internationalization.

Comment: Ok, great. The thing is that as I told you, I'm trying to make it your way, but I'm having some deploy error (I've edited my question so you can see it). So, this is not working for me at all. Thanks a lot anyway...

Comment: @elcadro you can't have two `<resource-bundle>` elements in a single `<portlet>` element. Edited my answer with a link to liferay development guide.

Comment: I'm not saying the opposite, but I can't make it work. 
I can't see in your link where or how they define a portlet with a message and a Language properties files at the same time. I already have the messages.properties defined and working, but I need to override the Language.properties file from liferay in order to put the spaces in the tab titles.
I've already solve this, using a hook plugin and it works fine. I really would like to know how to make it work your way, and I really appreciate your help, but still got nothing so I can't give your answer as the right one...

Comment: you can just put the keys for tab titles in the `message.properties` file and it should work. The file name need not be Language.properties, it can should whatever you have provided in the `resource-bundle` element. Just one question are you overriding liferay's jsp or you have developed your own jsp with the tabs?

Comment: Well, the thing is that it doesn't work if I put the keys in the message.properties files, and I'm pretty sure about this. That was my point from the beginning.
Answering your question, I've no idea how to override liferay's jsp's, so I guess I'm just defining my own jsp's with the tabs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30078/discussion-between-prakash-k-and-elcadro)